# BOT don't run in Web Chat

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I developed a simple bot, in test chat run and in debug enviroment run, but if I try it in Web Chat,  I have not any answer

[image]

Comment: Are you using iframe ?

Comment: @codelahiru Yes, I add an Iframe in web page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First check whether your web chat running inside the bot framework dashboard.

[image]
 2. Then check your secret and the code below.

```
<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/dxbot?s=[Your secret]" iframe>
```